# Basic Persian in plain XeTeX

Tags: xetex, xepersian, persian

I am trying to write Persian in plain-XeTeX as follows:

```
\font\frmnorm = "Nazli" at 24pt
\let\rm = \frmnorm
\uselanguage{farsi}
\rm
این فقط یک آزمایش است
\bye
```

...but it does not work for me well:

- the text is aligned to left
- the words are in the wrong order
- the characters in the words are not connected

I have tried multiple fonts as well as their OTF features.

Is there anybody using plain XePersian, not the XeLaTeX? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to do; you have to set also a different `\baselineskip`, though.

```
% Enable right to left typesetting
\TeXXeTstate=1

% define a font (this is one I have)
\font\frmnorm = "Scheherazade" at 24pt
\let\rm = \frmnorm
\uselanguage{farsi}

% At the start of a paragraph remove the indentation box then
% start right to left typesetting, after reinserting the indent
\everypar{{\setbox0=\lastbox}\beginR\kern\parindent}

\rm

این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است

این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است این فقط یک آزمایش است
این فقط یک آزمایش است

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, should one set `script` and `language` on font loading? (`\font\frmnorm = "Scheherazade:script=arabic;language=farsi"`)

Comment: @morbusg Possibly, but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks! I have added TeXXeTstate=1 _and_ OTF features and it started to work.